# What is the difference between identifiable and estimable?

Tags: estimation, references, identifiability

What is the difference between identifiable and estimable?

I know that when two models are identifiable they must have distinct parameters in  the corresponding parameter space. But what is the formal definition of estim-ability?  Say, if given a one-way ANOVA, $\mu-\tau_{i}$ are all estimable, so are their linear combinations. But how about $\frac{\mu-\tau_{i}}{\mu-\tau_{j}}$? This is not an estimable parameter since it is not a linear combination of those $\mu-\tau_{i}$'s. But it is still identifiable, right?

I want to know what is the difference and the relationship between these two notions.

Answer (score 2):

**Identifiability** is related to the mathematical model without consideration for any real-world noise in the observations.

**Estimability** takes measurement noise into account.

Jacquez, J.A. & P. Greif (1985) "Numerical Parameter Identifiability and Estimability: Integrating Identifiability, Estimability, and Optimal Sampling Design", *Mathematical Biosciences* 77(1):201-227.